# Query to return nodes that have no specific relationship within an already matched set of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The following statement creates the data I am trying to work with:

```
CREATE (p:P2 {id: '1', name: 'Arthur'})<-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 1, date:1}]-(:P2Data {wage: 1000})
CREATE (d2:P2Data {wage: 1100})-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 2, date:4}]->(p)
CREATE (d3:P2Data {wage: 1150})-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 3, date:3}]->(p)
CREATE (d3)-[:CANCELS]->(d2)
```

So, Arthur is created and initially has a wage of 1000. On **day 2** we add the info that the Wage will be **1100** from **day 4** onwards. On **day 3** we state that the wage will be increased to **1150**, which **cancels** the entry from day 2.

Now, if I look at the history as it was valid for a given point in time, when the point in time is 2, the following history is correct:

- day 1 - wage 1000
- day 4 - wage 1100

when the point in time is 3, the following history is correct:

- day 1 - wage 1000
- day 3 - wage 1150

expressed in graph terms, when I match the P2Data based on the :EXPANDS relationship, I need those that are not cancelled by any other P2Data node that has **also been matched**.

This is my attempt so far:

```
MATCH p=(:P2 {id: '1'})<-[x1:EXPANDS]-(d1:P2Data)
WHERE x1.recorded <= 3
WITH x1.date as date, 
FILTER(n in nodes(p) 
  WHERE n:P2Data AND 
  SIZE(FILTER(n2 IN nodes(p) WHERE (n2:P2Data)-[:CANCELS]->(n))) = 0) AS result
RETURN date, result
```

The idea was to only get those `n in nodes(p)` where there are no paths pointing to it via the `:CANCELS` relationship.

Since I am still new to this and somehow cypher hasn't clicked yet for me, feel free to discard that query completely.

Answer (score 1):

```
MATCH (:P2 {id: '1'})<-[x1:EXPANDS]-(d1:P2Data)
WHERE x1.recorded <= 3
WITH x1.date AS valid_date, x1.recorded AS transaction_date, d1.wage AS wage
ORDER BY valid_date
WITH COLLECT({v: valid_date, t: transaction_date, w:wage}) AS dates
WITH REDUCE(x = [HEAD(dates)], date IN TAIL(dates)|
    CASE
    WHEN date.v = LAST(x).v AND date.t > LAST(x).t THEN x[..-1] + [date]
    WHEN date.t > LAST(x).t THEN x + [date]
    ELSE x 
    END) AS results
UNWIND results AS result
RETURN result.v, result.w
```

I'm trying to think of a way to model this better, but I'm honestly pretty stumped.

Comment: Yeah, on further reflection, I don't think this problem space is a very good match for a graph. If you could make relationships connecting the `P2Data` nodes somehow to reflect progress through valid times, you could develop a graphier solution, but that introduces some constraints of its own. If comparisons are done by property sort and not by path, you aren't gaining anything by using a graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your data model by removing the `CANCELS` relationship, and instead add an optional `canceled` date to the `EXPANDS` relationship type, you can greatly simplify the required query.

For example, create the test data:

```
CREATE (p:P2 {id: '1', name: 'Arthur'})<-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 1, date:1}]-(:P2Data {wage: 1000})
CREATE (d2:P2Data {wage: 1100})-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 2, date:4, canceled: 3}]->(p)
CREATE (d3:P2Data {wage: 1150})-[:EXPANDS {recorded: 3, date:3}]->(p)
```

Perform simple query:

```
MATCH p=(:P2 {id: '1'})<-[x1:EXPANDS]-(d1:P2Data)
WHERE x1.recorded <= 3 AND (x1.canceled IS NULL OR x1.canceled > 3)
RETURN x1.date AS date, d1
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Every time you write a data point, though, you'll have to go back and update previous data points to reflect the cancellation. it's the same problem with the `CANCELED` relationship that flq was struggling with above. The bitemporal model kinda relies on an inherent relationship between times that is difficult to dynamically create and mutate in a graph.

Comment: An `EXPANDS` relationship only needs a `canceled` value if that value is between its `recorded` and `date` values, which should be rare, so not all previous points have to be updated. But, yes, you would have to check to see what needs to be updated every time.

Comment: But If wage writes are infrequent compared to reads, then this may be acceptable.

Comment: Having to conditionally edit *some* previous data points seems worse than having to edit *all* previous data points, from a complexity standpoint.

Comment: Writes are expensive.

Comment: The problem doesn't require any writes at all.

Comment: My solution will rarely require any writes.

Comment: I'll play with that, thanks...tbh, I have yet to meet a datastore where bitemporal relations can be expressed trivially :) The main problem domain I'm working towards is "graphy", but bitemporality is an additional requirement. I would consider cancellations to be more seldom than other operations.